# MPI dynamically allocation arrays

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a problem with a dynamically allocation of arrays.

This code, if I use a static allocation, runs without problem...

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){  

    int size, rank;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int lowerBound = 0, upperBound = 0, dimArrayTemp, x, z;
    int dimBulk = size - 1, nPart, cnt;


    FILE *pf;
    pf = fopen("in.txt","r");
    int array_value = fscanf(pf,"%d",&array_value);
    float ins_array_value;

    float *arrayTemp, *bulkSum,*s,*a;

    arrayTemp =(float*)malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
    bulkSum = (float*)malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
    s =(float*) malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
    a =(float*) malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));

    int j=0;

    while(!feof(pf)){
        fscanf(pf,"%f",&ins_array_value);
        a[j] = ins_array_value;
        j++;
    }
    fclose(pf); 

    float presum, valFinal;

    if(size <= array_value){
        if (rank == MASTER){
            nPart = array_value/size; 
            int countPair;
            if((array_value % size) != 0){
                countPair = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

                if(i == 0){
                    lowerBound = upperBound;
                    upperBound += nPart - 1; 
                }
                else{
                    lowerBound += nPart;
                    upperBound += nPart;
                    if(countPair == 0 && i == size - 1)
                        upperBound = array_value - 1;
                }
                dimArrayTemp = upperBound - lowerBound;
                //float arrayTemp[dimArrayTemp];
                for( x = lowerBound, z = 0; x <= upperBound; x++, z++){
                    arrayTemp[z] = a[x];
                }
                if (i > 0){
                    //send array size
                    MPI_Send(&z,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    //send value array
                    MPI_Send(arrayTemp,z,MPI_INT,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
                else{

                    for (int h = 1;h <= dimArrayTemp; h++)
                        arrayTemp[h] = arrayTemp[h-1] + arrayTemp[h]; 
                    bulkSum[0] = arrayTemp[dimArrayTemp];
                    for (int h = 0; h <= dimArrayTemp; h++)
                        s[h] = arrayTemp[h];
                }

            }       
        }
        else{
                //recieve array size
            MPI_Recv(&z,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            MPI_Recv(arrayTemp,z,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            for(int h = 1; h < z; h++){
                arrayTemp[h] = arrayTemp[h-1] + arrayTemp[h];
                presum = arrayTemp[h];
            }


            MPI_Send(&presum,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (rank == MASTER){

            for (int i = 1; i<size;i++){
                MPI_Recv(&presum,1,MPI_INT,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                bulkSum[i] = presum;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i<=dimBulk; i++){
                bulkSum[i] = bulkSum[i-1] +bulkSum[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<dimBulk;i++){
                valFinal = bulkSum[i];
                cnt = i+1;
                MPI_Send(&valFinal,1,MPI_INT,cnt,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
        else{

            MPI_Recv(&valFinal,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            for(int i = 0; i<z;i++){
                arrayTemp[i] = arrayTemp[i] + valFinal;
            }
            MPI_Send(arrayTemp,z,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        if(rank == MASTER){
            for(int i =1;i<size;i++){
                MPI_Recv(arrayTemp,z,MPI_INT,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                for(int v=0, w =dimArrayTemp+1 ;v<z;v++, w++){
                    s[w] = arrayTemp[v];
                }   
                dimArrayTemp += z;
            }
            int count = 0;
            for(int c = 0;c<array_value;c++){
                printf("s[%d] = %f \n",count++,s[c]);
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR!!!\t number of procs (%d) is higher than array size(%d)!\n", size, array_value);
        //fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Finalize();
    }
    free(arrayTemp);
    free(s);
    free(a);
    free(bulkSum);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;   
}
```

This is a specific declaration of arrays:

```
float *arrayTemp, *bulkSum,*s,*a;

arrayTemp =(float*)malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
bulkSum = (float*)malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
s =(float*) malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
a =(float*) malloc(array_value*sizeof(float));
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm deleted reference for arrays in MPI_Send(); and MPI_Recv(); and condition master, the same error is occurred: a process exited on signal 6 (Aborted).

Comment: Note that you are using `MPI_INT` everywhere in your code, even when sending and receiving `float` values! Also, this line is wrong: `int array_value = fscanf(pf,"%d",&array_value);`. The return value of `fscanf` is the number of input items assigned and it should not be assigned to `array_value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common rookie mistake. One often sees MPI tutorials where variables are passed by address to MPI calls, e.g. `MPI_Send(&a, ...);`. The *address-of* operator (`&`) is used to get the address of the variable and that address is passed to MPI as a buffer area for the operation. While `&` returns the address of the actual data storage for scalar variables and arrays, when applied to pointers it returns the address where the address pointed to is stored.

The simplest solution is to stick to the following rule: never use `&` with arrays or dynamically allocated memory, e.g.:

```
int a;
MPI_Send(&a, ...);
```

but

```
int a[10];
MPI_Send(a, ...);
```

and

```
int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
MPI_Send(a, ...);
```

---

Also, as noted by @talonmies, you are only allocating the arrays in the master process. You should remove the conditional surrounding the allocation calls.

Comment: The buffers also are not being dynamically allocated on any nodes in the communicator other than the master.

Comment: Good catch! To be honest, I only had a cursory look over the code.

Answer (score -3):

making arrays static prevents the arrays to be modified in other functions thus preventing errors. If making arrays static causes no errors then  let it be static and use them by call by reference or it might be a good idea to make the arrays global as a try.